# How to save as compressed json when using structured streaming (JAVA)?

Tags: java, json, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use as less memory as possible when saving json files into HDFS.
Is it possible to save not as json file but as compressed json?
I'm using `writeStream()` (Java).
I can save as gzip file by using `option("compression","gzip")`,
but what I really want is **[compressed json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201647/what-is-compressed-json)**
Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible out of the box. You'd have to write your own custom data source format to do so. You could also start with `foreach*` operators and do the compression and write yourself.

Comment: I looked for a contribution on GitHub, but found nothing for you.